# WPF: Change Colors of Elements in User Control if "IsEnabled=False"

Tags: wpf, xaml, user-controls, grid

I have a UserControl which consists of a grid with 3 columns:

```
Name="Test">

<UserControl.Resources>
    <ResourceDictionary>
        <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
            ...
        </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
    </ResourceDictionary>
</UserControl.Resources>

<Grid Width="{StaticResource DoubleOverallWidthUserControls}" Height="{StaticResource DoubleHeightControls}">
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="auto" />
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="{StaticResource GridLengthUserControlLabel}" />
        <ColumnDefinition Width="{StaticResource GridLengthUserControlContent}" />
        <ColumnDefinition Width="{StaticResource GridLengthUserControlUnits}" />
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

    <Border
        Grid.Row="0"
        Grid.Column="0"
        BorderBrush="{StaticResource BrushTextInputBorder}"
        BorderThickness="0,0,0,1"
        Cursor="Arrow">
        <TextBlock
            x:Name="TextBlockLabel"
            Width="{StaticResource DoubleWidthUserControlLabel}"
            VerticalAlignment="Center"
            DockPanel.Dock="Top"
            TextAlignment="Left" />
    </Border>
    <Border BorderBrush="{StaticResource BrushBorder}" CornerRadius="3,3,0,0" Grid.Row="0"
        Grid.Column="1" Background="White">
    <TextBox
        x:Name="TextBoxText"
        Width="{StaticResource DoubleWidthUserControlContent}" />
        <Border.Style>
            <Style TargetType="Border">
                <Style.Triggers>
                    <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding ElementName=Test, Path=IsEnabled}" Value="False">
                        <Setter Property="Background" Value="Gray"></Setter>
                    </DataTrigger>
                </Style.Triggers>
            </Style>
        </Border.Style>
    </Border>

    <TextBlock
        x:Name="TextBlockUnit"
        Grid.Row="0"
        Grid.Column="2"
        Width="{StaticResource DoubleWidthUserControlUnits}"
        Margin="10,0,0,0"
        VerticalAlignment="Center" />
</Grid>
```

Now I want to change the following things in my control if it is disabled:

- column 1: grid bottom border color
- column 2: background color of the white border element in which the transparent textbox is wrapped

can someone help me?

Comment: You could use an `IValueConverter` or a `DataTrigger`for this.

Comment: can you provide the code snippet of usercontrol?

Comment: here you go @SushilMate

Comment: I inserted a datatrigger, but i doesn't work

Comment: @jimmmmyjooo basically you want to change the border background once your control disabled?

Comment: exactly @SushilMate

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A Style Setter only works when you have not set the property directly. This is because the direct assignment creates a so-called local value, which has higher precedence than the value from a Style Setter. See [Dependency Property Value Precedence](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wpf/advanced/dependency-property-value-precedence) for details.

Since you want to disable two borders, you may create the following Style in Resource:

```
<UserControl.Resources>
    <Style x:Key="BorderStyle" TargetType="Border">
        <Setter Property="Background" Value="White"/>
        <Style.Triggers>
            <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding ElementName=Test, Path=IsEnabled}"
                         Value="False">
                 <Setter Property="Background" Value="Gray"/>
            </DataTrigger>
        </Style.Triggers>
    </Style>
</UserControl.Resources>
```

Assign this style to your border.

```
<Border Style="{StaticResource BorderStyle}"/>
```

---

You could even make this a default Style in the UserControl by omitting the `x:Key`

```
<UserControl.Resources>
    <Style TargetType="Border">
        ...
    </Style>
</UserControl.Resources>
```

so that you would not have to explicitly set the Style property if the Buttons:

```
<Border>
    ...
</Border>
```

Comment: The answer missed an explanation why the Style in the question didn't work. I've added it, since it's copied from my answer anyway (including formatting).

Comment: Is it? What might be lacking?

Comment: It's all ok. Leave it as it is. But for the future, don't just copy from other people's post without mentioning that. Sometimes it's even better not to write an own answer at all, but simply suggest an improvement in a comment.